# How to enable Digital Clock Preferences in LXDE

Tags: system-clock

I am trying to set the system time to Local time rather than UTC. The LXDE Digital Clock shows UTC and an application I am running remotely and viewing in Epiphany is logging UTC time stamps rather than the desired Local timestamps.

I have tried using raspi-config Internationalisation Options/change timezone to change the system date & time and that seems to work and is persistent across reboots.

```
Current default timezone: 'America/Costa Rica'
Local time is now:     Tue Oct 27 08:07:52 CST 2015
Universal time is now: Tue Oct 27 14:07:52 UTC 2015
```

However, `date` shows `Tue Oct 27 14:05:26 America 2015`, and the Digital Clock in LXDE shows **02:07:52 PM**

They are both showing UTC time.

I need `date` to show `Tue Oct 27 08.07:52 America 2015`.

I am assuming I should be able to change the Digital Clock preferences to show Local Time rather than UTC? But the Digital Clock preferences is greyed out - hence my question.

However if I am barking up the wrong tree and someone knows a better or more correct way to achieve my objective, **system to use Local time not UTC**, please help.

Comment: *Most* of this isn't really pi-specific, and you may want to ask about that on on our larger sibling site [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), or [LXDE's own forum](http://forum.lxde.org/).  However, the bit about `raspi-config` is a bit shady and worth examination here.

Comment: Worth noting all `rasp-config` does for this is invoke `dpkg-reconfigure locales` and `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`.

Comment: Thanks Goldilocks, I did try using dpkg-reconfigure tzdata which as you say essentially is the same as using rasp-config. But neither are making the system use Local time.

Comment: This problem went away after a clean install of Raspbian from Noobs.

Comment: @goldilocks please feel free to delete this question if you consider it a duplicate. I am new to StackExchange and I can't find a way to delete it myself.

Comment: There should be a button there, but it's actually better if you don't.  I'm kind of irritated the system auto-deleted the duplicate, actually.